# select dinámicos se desactiven al seleccionar un valor - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo un select dinamico que funciona de la siguiente forma explico:

Hay un input donde agrego un valor "X" y al darle clic al boton que se llama "generar select" me agreaga cantidad de valores que agregue en el input

Cuando selecciono un valor del select este me carga otro select dinamico donde me aparece los números faltantes de forma ascendente y asi hasta seleccionar el ultimo numero, y el ultimo select que se va generando va mostrando un boton que se llama "crear".

**Opción 1**

Lo que necesito es cada select dinamico donde va apareciendo el boton crear al seleccionar algun valor vaya quedando dedactivado y que solo muestre el valor seleccionado.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

//input dinamico

import Row from "./Row2";

let initialState = {
  first: null,
  arraySelect: [],
  arraySelect2: []
};

function test(props) {
  //input dinamico

  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [initialeRow, setInitialRow] = useState({ nombre: "" });
  //SELECT2
  const [selectedNumbers, setSelectedNumbers] = useState([]);

  const handleOnChange = (index, value) => {
    const copy = rows.map((e, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        e.nombre = value;
      }

      return e;
    });

    setRows([...copy]);
  };

  //division
  const [number, setNumber] = useState();

  //Mostrar 4
  const [modocuatro, setModoCuatro] = useState(null);

  //Mostrar 5
  const [modoboton, setModoBoton] = useState(null);

  //modo cuatro
  const handleClick_cuatro = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setModoCuatro(true);

    global.multi = global.nuevo * global.select1;

    console.log(global.multi + "resultado");
  };

  const handleInput_division = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setNumber({ ...number, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleInput_division2 = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setSelect(value);

    setNumber({ ...number, [name]: value });
    setInitialRow({ nombre: value * 1 + 1 });
  };

  const [arraySelect, setarraySelect] = useState(initialState.arraySelect);

  const [arraySelect2, setarraySelect2] = useState(initialState.arraySelect2);

  const [numberIni, setnumberIni] = useState(initialState.first);

  const [numberIni2, setnumberIni2] = useState(initialState.first);

  const getArray = (value) => {
    let arr = [];
    {
      let reco = Math.round(numberIni - parseInt(value));
      console.log(reco + "mi");

      if (parseInt(value) == numberIni) {
        return false;
      }
      Array(reco)
        .fill(1)
        .map((value2, key) => {
          arr.push(parseInt(value) + parseInt(key + 1));
        });
    }
    return arr;
  };

  const setSelect = (value) => {
    //debugger;
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
      setModoBoton(true);
    }
    if (isArray) {
      setInitialRow({ nombre: value });
      setRows([...rows, { nombre: value }]);
    }
  };

  //segundo array
  const getArray2 = (value) => {
    const numValue2 = parseInt(value, 10);
    const arr2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numValue2 - 1; i++) {
      arr2.push(numValue2 - i - 1);
    }
    if (arr2.length) {
      return arr2;
    }
  };

  //segundo select
  const setSelect_select2 = (value) => {
    let mi = global.division2020;
    let isArray2 = getArray2(value);
    if (isArray2) {
      setarraySelect2([...arraySelect2, isArray2]);

      setInitialRow({ nombre: initialeRow.nombre * 1 + 1 });

      setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);
    }
  };

  //SEGUNDO SELECT
  const handleChange = (index, value) => {
    const tmpSelectedNumbers = [...selectedNumbers];
    tmpSelectedNumbers[index] = value;
    setSelectedNumbers(tmpSelectedNumbers);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    setnumberIni(event.target.numberIni.value);
    setnumberIni2(event.target.numberIni2.value - 1);
  };

  const resetFormtodo = () => {
    setnumberIni(null);
    setnumberIni2(null);

    setRows([]);
    setarraySelect([]);
    setarraySelect2([]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h6>INGRESA UN PRIMER VALOR "GRUPOS"</h6>

            <div class="input-group ">
              <select
                name="numberIni2"
                class="form-control"
                onChange={handleInput_division}
              >
                <option value="0" selected>
                  Seleccione
                </option>

                <option value="10"> 10 </option>

                <option value="20">20</option>
              </select>

              <br />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h6>INGRESA UN SEGUNDO VALOR</h6>
            <div class="input-group ">
              <input
                type="number"
                name="numberIni"
                placeholder="0"
                class="form-control"
              />
              <br />
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                GENERAR
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <br />
      <div>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <br /> <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          {numberIni && (
            <div>
              <h6>Criterio Para Equipos Clasificados a la Siguiente Fase</h6>
              <label>
                <font size="2">
                  1° Clasificados Por Grupo <br />
                  Clasificarán a Siguiente Fases Los Primeros :&nbsp;{" "}
                </font>
              </label>
              <select onChange={handleInput_division2} name="numberIni3">
                <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
                  .fill(1)
                  .map((value, key) => {
                    return <option value={key + 1}>{key + 1} Equipos</option>;
                  })}
              </select>

              <label>
                <font size="2">&nbsp;Equipos De Cada Grupo </font>{" "}
              </label>

              <label>
                <font size="2">
                  {" "}
                  &nbsp;{" "}
                  {modoboton ? (
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-primary"
                      onClick={handleClick_cuatro}
                    >
                      Generar select
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <></>
                  )}{" "}
                </font>{" "}
              </label>

              <hr />
              {modocuatro ? (
                <div class="col-sm-10" style={{ top: "-20px" }}>
                  {Array(parseInt(numberIni2))
                    .fill(1)
                    .map((value, key2) => {
                      return (
                        <div>
                          {arraySelect[key2] && (
                            <>
                              <label>
                                <font size="2">
                                  &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                  <label>
                                    <font size="2">
                                      {" "}
                                      &nbsp;{" "}
                                      <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                          <h6>
                                            Segundos Clasificados Por Grupo
                                          </h6>
                                          <label>
                                            <font size="2">
                                              Clasificarán a Siguiente Fases Los
                                              de Mejor Promedio :
                                              <select
                                                onChange={(e) =>
                                                  handleChange(
                                                    0,
                                                    e.target.value
                                                  )
                                                }
                                                name=""
                                                id=""
                                              >
                                                <option value="seleccione">
                                                  Seleccione
                                                </option>
                                                {Array(parseInt(numberIni2))
                                                  .fill(1)
                                                  .map((value, key) => {
                                                    return (
                                                      <option
                                                        value={numberIni2 - key}
                                                      >
                                                        {numberIni2 - key}{" "}
                                                        Equipos
                                                      </option>
                                                    );
                                                  })}
                                              </select>{" "}
                                              {console.log(arraySelect)}{" "}
                                              Ubicados en la
                                              {rows.length === 1 && (
                                                <div
                                                  className="col-sm-2"
                                                  style={{
                                                    top: "-27px",
                                                    right: "-135%"
                                                  }}
                                                >
                                                  <button
                                                    type="submit"
                                                    className="btn btn-primary"
                                                    onClick={() => {
                                                      setSelect_select2(
                                                        selectedNumbers[0]
                                                      );
                                                    }}
                                                  >
                                                    crear
                                                  </button>
                                                </div>
                                              )}
                                            </font>{" "}
                                          </label>

                                          {Array(parseInt(numberIni2))
                                            .fill(1)
                                            .map((value, key2) => {
                                              return (
                                                <div>
                                                  {arraySelect2[key2] && (
                                                    <>
                                                      <h6>
                                                        Segundos Clasificados
                                                        Por Grupo
                                                      </h6>
                                                      <label>
                                                        <font size="2">
                                                          Clasificarán a
                                                          Siguiente Fases Los de
                                                          Mejor Promedio :
                                                          <select
                                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                              handleChange(
                                                                key2 + 1,
                                                                e.target.value
                                                              )
                                                            }
                                                            name=""
                                                            id=""
                                                          >
                                                            <option value="seleccione">
                                                              Seleccione
                                                            </option>
                                                            {arraySelect2[
                                                              key2
                                                            ].map(
                                                              (value, key3) => {
                                                                return (
                                                                  <option
                                                                    value={
                                                                      arraySelect2[
                                                                        key2
                                                                      ][key3]
                                                                    }
                                                                  >
                                                                    {
                                                                      arraySelect2[
                                                                        key2
                                                                      ][key3]
                                                                    }{" "}
                                                                    Equipos
                                                                  </option>
                                                                );
                                                              }
                                                            )}
                                                          </select>{" "}
                                                          Ubicados en la
                                                          {key2 ===
                                                            rows.length - 2 && (
                                                            <div
                                                              className="col-sm-2"
                                                              style={{
                                                                top: "-27px",
                                                                right: "-135%"
                                                              }}
                                                            >
                                                              <button
                                                                type="submit"
                                                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                                                onClick={() => {
                                                                  setSelect_select2(
                                                                    selectedNumbers[
                                                                      key2 + 1
                                                                    ]
                                                                  );
                                                                }}
                                                              >
                                                                crear
                                                              </button>
                                                            </div>
                                                          )}
                                                        </font>{" "}
                                                      </label>
                                                    </>
                                                  )}
                                                </div>
                                              );
                                            })}
                                        </div>

                                        <div
                                          className="col-sm-2"
                                          style={{ top: "-40px" }}
                                        >
                                          {rows.map((e, index) => (
                                            <Row
                                              nombre={e.nombre}
                                              index={index}
                                              onChange={(index, value) =>
                                                handleOnChange(index, value)
                                              }
                                              key={index}
                                            />
                                          ))}
                                        </div>
                                      </div>{" "}
                                    </font>{" "}
                                  </label>
                                </font>{" "}
                              </label>
                            </>
                          )}
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                </div>
              ) : (
                <></>
              )}

              {numberIni2 && (
                <input
                  onClick={() => resetFormtodo()}
                  type="button"
                  value="Reiniciar"
                />
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default test;
```

//row.js

```js
const Row = (props) => {
  const { onChange, onRemove, nombre, index } = props;
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <h6> </h6>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      
      <input
      disabled
        value={nombre  * 1 + 1 +  " Posición"}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(index, e.target.value)} 
        placeholder="Decrementar"
      />


      
    </div>
  );
};
export default Row;
```

**mi algoritmo hace lo siguiente:**

1. cuando se inicia aparece un select y un input donde se deben agregar cualquier valor luego de darle en el boton "generar".
2. despues  me genera un select con la cantidad de numeros  que coloque en el input, luego selecciono algún numero en el select que me aparece,  luego le doy al  boton que dice "generar select".
3. despues me genera un select y un input de forma dinamica , y cada vez que selecciono un numero en el select  y le doy  al boton "crear" se me genera otro select de forma dinamica con los valores restantes.

**Lo que necesito**

Cada vez que le doy Click a los Botones Crear (Cual es este Botón, veo 2 que dicen Generar, no crear?), quiero que los select dinámico (Cuales son los select dinámico veo 2 select) se desactiven y que solo deje seleccionar el select dinámico (cual es este otro select??)

https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-cache-ppes4?file=/src/App.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: alguien me puede ayudar ?

Comment: puedes dar una mejor explicación de lo que hace tu script, lo que quieres que haga ... y lo que esta haciendo mal???

Comment: listo, al final de la pregunta redacte mejor paso a paso como funciona el algoritmo y tambien lo envie por codesandbox .

Comment: sigo sin entender ... puedes identificar cual es el select dinámico??? acabo de editar tu post y coloque los puntos que no se entienden .. puedes mejorar la identificación de los elementos???

Comment: ahora te hago la otra pregunta que has intentado ??? para deshabilitar el select que mencionas ...

Comment: lo que necesito  es que donde aparece los select dinamicos que son donde aparece el boton de crear , cuando selecione un valor del select que quede deshabilitado al darle al botón "crear" y asi cada vez que vaya apareciendo los select dinamicos  al darle el boton "crear" .   los select dinamicos que necesito que vayan quedando deshabilitados al darle clic en el boton crear son los que aparecen en la linea 268 y  336 en el https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-cache-ppes4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: que has intentado ??? para deshabilitar el select que mencionas ...

Comment: no veo ese boton en tu ejemplo: https://i.imgur.com/z9ohw9W.png

Comment: en el codesanbox aparece el boton , de hecho la foto que tome es de ahi mismo, respecto a si he probado deshabilitar los select dinamicos la respuesta es si, pero el problema es que si los deshabilito de forma predeterminada no me deja seleccionar nada en los select dinamicos y la idea es que se vayan deshabilitando solo cuando le de en el boton crear .

Comment: no siento pero no puedo reproducir lo que dices que funciona ...

Comment: ya se por que no te aparece el boton , no escribas el numero uno ya que si el valor del input y el valor del select es el mismo el boton no se generea.

Comment: eso es asi o es un bug???

Comment: es asi, asi fue implementado con esa condición

Comment: ha ok pero eso no lo dice tu post ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguro hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero yo te recomiendo esta manera que está algo hardcodeada.

Sería una solución similar a la de tu otra pregunta: [que se vaya deshabilitando los botones anteriores de mi array - reactjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/498468/que-se-vaya-deshabilitando-los-botones-anteriores-de-mi-array-reactjs/498521#498521).

El objetivo es condicionar qué tipo de `<Select>` se mostrará, si uno con su atributo `disabled` habilitado u otro con el mismo atributo deshabilitado.

El condicionamiento es parecido, o casi igual, al de la pregunta que te cité.

Con el primero sería ver si `rows.length === 1`, es decir si estamos en el primer select.

De ser así mostramos un select con el atributo  `disabled={false}`:

```
 {rows.length === 1 && (
        <select
            onChange={(e) =>
            handleChange(
                0,
                e.target.value
            )
            }
            name=""
            id=""
            disabled={false}
        >
```

Luego hacemos exactamente lo mismo pero preguntando lo contrario `rows.length !== 1`.

Y en caso positivo, esta vez ponemos el `disabled={true}`:

```
 {rows.length !== 1 && (
        <select
            onChange={(e) =>
            handleChange(
                0,
                e.target.value
            )
            }
            name=""
            id=""
            disabled={true}
        >
```

Una vez más, repetimos la misma lógica exactamente igual pero esta vez haciendo la validación para ver si estamos en el último select preguntando `key2 === rows.length - 2`.

De ser así, mostramos el select con su `disabled={false}`:

```
 {key2 ===
        rows.length - 2 && (
        <select
            onChange={(e) =>
            handleChange(
                key2 + 1,
                e.target.value
            )
            }
            name=""
            id=""
            disabled={false}
        >
```

Por ultimo, repetimos el mismo procedimiento anterior preguntado lo contrario `key2 !==rows.length - 2` y asegurándonos de que el select quede deshabilitado en caso de que no sea el ultimo:

```
 {key2 !==
        rows.length - 2 && (
        <select
            onChange={(e) =>
            handleChange(
                key2 + 1,
                e.target.value
            )
            }
            name=""
            id=""
            disabled={true}
        >
```

Pero de esta manera perderíamos el número que seleccionamos en cada select desactivado.

Para evitar ese problema, hay que ponerle en el atributo `value` de cada select desactivado el valor del número que se guardó en el array `selectedNumbers`.

Serían `value={ selectedNumbers[key2]}`
y `value={ selectedNumbers[key2 + 1]}` respectivamente en cada select.

Todo el código quedaría así:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

//input dinamico

import Row from "./Row2";

let initialState = {
  first: null,
  arraySelect: [],
  arraySelect2: []
};

function test(props) {
  //input dinamico

  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [initialeRow, setInitialRow] = useState({ nombre: "" });
  //SELECT2
  const [selectedNumbers, setSelectedNumbers] = useState([]);

  const handleOnChange = (index, value) => {
    const copy = rows.map((e, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        e.nombre = value;
      }

      return e;
    });

    setRows([...copy]);
  };

  //division
  const [number, setNumber] = useState();

  //Mostrar 4
  const [modocuatro, setModoCuatro] = useState(null);

  //Mostrar 5
  const [modoboton, setModoBoton] = useState(null);

  //modo cuatro
  const handleClick_cuatro = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setModoCuatro(true);

    global.multi = global.nuevo * global.select1;

    console.log(global.multi + "resultado");
  };

  const handleInput_division = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setNumber({ ...number, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleInput_division2 = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setSelect(value);

    setNumber({ ...number, [name]: value });
    setInitialRow({ nombre: value * 1 + 1 });
  };

  const [arraySelect, setarraySelect] = useState(initialState.arraySelect);

  const [arraySelect2, setarraySelect2] = useState(initialState.arraySelect2);

  const [numberIni, setnumberIni] = useState(initialState.first);

  const [numberIni2, setnumberIni2] = useState(initialState.first);

  const getArray = (value) => {
    let arr = [];
    {
      let reco = Math.round(numberIni - parseInt(value));
      console.log(reco + "mi");

      if (parseInt(value) == numberIni) {
        return false;
      }
      Array(reco)
        .fill(1)
        .map((value2, key) => {
          arr.push(parseInt(value) + parseInt(key + 1));
        });
    }
    return arr;
  };

  const setSelect = (value) => {
    //debugger;
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
      setModoBoton(true);
    }
    if (isArray) {
      setInitialRow({ nombre: value });
      setRows([...rows, { nombre: value }]);
    }
  };

  //segundo array
  const getArray2 = (value) => {
    const numValue2 = parseInt(value, 10);
    const arr2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numValue2 - 1; i++) {
      arr2.push(numValue2 - i - 1);
    }
    if (arr2.length) {
      return arr2;
    }
  };

  //segundo select
  const setSelect_select2 = (value) => {
    let mi = global.division2020;
    let isArray2 = getArray2(value);
    if (isArray2) {
      setarraySelect2([...arraySelect2, isArray2]);

      setInitialRow({ nombre: initialeRow.nombre * 1 + 1 });

      setRows([...rows, initialeRow]);
    }
  };

  //SEGUNDO SELECT
  const handleChange = (index, value) => {
    const tmpSelectedNumbers = [...selectedNumbers];
    tmpSelectedNumbers[index] = value;
    setSelectedNumbers(tmpSelectedNumbers);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    setnumberIni(event.target.numberIni.value);
    setnumberIni2(event.target.numberIni2.value - 1);
  };

  const resetFormtodo = () => {
    setnumberIni(null);
    setnumberIni2(null);

    setRows([]);
    setarraySelect([]);
    setarraySelect2([]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h6>INGRESA UN PRIMER VALOR "GRUPOS"</h6>

            <div class="input-group ">
              <select
                name="numberIni2"
                class="form-control"
                onChange={handleInput_division}
              >
                <option value="0" selected>
                  Seleccione
                </option>

                <option value="10"> 10 </option>

                <option value="20">20</option>
              </select>

              <br />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h6>INGRESA UN SEGUNDO VALOR</h6>
            <div class="input-group ">
              <input
                type="number"
                name="numberIni"
                placeholder="0"
                class="form-control"
              />
              <br />
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                GENERAR
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <br />
      <div>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <br /> <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          {numberIni && (
            <div>
              <h6>Criterio Para Equipos Clasificados a la Siguiente Fase</h6>
              <label>
                <font size="2">
                  1° Clasificados Por Grupo <br />
                  Clasificarán a Siguiente Fases Los Primeros :&nbsp;{" "}
                </font>
              </label>
              <select onChange={handleInput_division2} name="numberIni3">
                <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
                  .fill(1)
                  .map((value, key) => {
                    return <option value={key + 1}>{key + 1} Equipos</option>;
                  })}
              </select>

              <label>
                <font size="2">&nbsp;Equipos De Cada Grupo </font>{" "}
              </label>

              <label>
                <font size="2">
                  {" "}
                  &nbsp;{" "}
                  {modoboton ? (
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-primary"
                      onClick={handleClick_cuatro}
                    >
                      Generar select
                    </button>
                  ) : (
                    <></>
                  )}{" "}
                </font>{" "}
              </label>

              <hr />
              {modocuatro ? (
                <div class="col-sm-10" style={{ top: "-20px" }}>
                  {Array(parseInt(numberIni2))
                    .fill(1)
                    .map((value, key2) => {
                      return (
                        <div>
                          {arraySelect[key2] && (
                            <>
                              <label>
                                <font size="2">
                                  &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                  <label>
                                    <font size="2">
                                      {" "}
                                      &nbsp;{" "}
                                      <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                          <h6>
                                            Segundos Clasificados Por Grupo
                                          </h6>
                                          <label>
                                            <font size="2">
                                              Clasificarán a Siguiente Fases Los
                                              de Mejor Promedio :
                                              {rows.length === 1 && (
                                                <select
                                                  onChange={(e) =>
                                                    handleChange(
                                                      0,
                                                      e.target.value
                                                    )
                                                  }
                                                  name=""
                                                  id=""
                                                  disabled={false}
                                                >
                                                  <option value="seleccione">
                                                    Seleccione
                                                  </option>
                                                  {Array(parseInt(numberIni2))
                                                    .fill(1)
                                                    .map((value, key) => {
                                                      return (
                                                        <option
                                                          value={
                                                            numberIni2 - key
                                                          }
                                                        >
                                                          {numberIni2 - key}{" "}
                                                          Equipos
                                                        </option>
                                                      );
                                                    })}
                                                </select>
                                              )}
                                              {rows.length !== 1 && (
                                                <select
                                                  onChange={(e) =>
                                                    handleChange(
                                                      0,
                                                      e.target.value
                                                    )
                                                  }
                                                  name=""
                                                  id=""
                                                  disabled={true}
                                                >
                                                  <option value="seleccione">
                                                    Seleccione
                                                  </option>
                                                  {Array(parseInt(numberIni2))
                                                    .fill(1)
                                                    .map((value, key) => {
                                                      return (
                                                        <option
                                                          value={
                                                            numberIni2 - key
                                                          }
                                                        >
                                                          {numberIni2 - key}{" "}
                                                          Equipos
                                                        </option>
                                                      );
                                                    })}
                                                </select>
                                              )}{" "}
                                              {console.log(arraySelect)}{" "}
                                              Ubicados en la
                                              {rows.length === 1 && (
                                                <div
                                                  className="col-sm-2"
                                                  style={{
                                                    top: "-27px",
                                                    right: "-135%"
                                                  }}
                                                >
                                                  <button
                                                    type="submit"
                                                    className="btn btn-primary"
                                                    onClick={() => {
                                                      setSelect_select2(
                                                        selectedNumbers[0]
                                                      );
                                                    }}
                                                  >
                                                    crear
                                                  </button>
                                                </div>
                                              )}
                                            </font>{" "}
                                          </label>

                                          {Array(parseInt(numberIni2))
                                            .fill(1)
                                            .map((value, key2) => {
                                              return (
                                                <div>
                                                  {arraySelect2[key2] && (
                                                    <>
                                                      <h6>
                                                        Segundos Clasificados
                                                        Por Grupo
                                                      </h6>
                                                      <label>
                                                        <font size="2">
                                                          Clasificarán a
                                                          Siguiente Fases Los de
                                                          Mejor Promedio :
                                                          {key2 ===
                                                            rows.length - 2 && (
                                                            <select
                                                              onChange={(e) =>
                                                                handleChange(
                                                                  key2 + 1,
                                                                  e.target.value
                                                                )
                                                              }
                                                              name=""
                                                              id=""
                                                              disabled={false}
                                                            >
                                                              <option value="seleccione">
                                                                Seleccione
                                                              </option>
                                                              {arraySelect2[
                                                                key2
                                                              ].map(
                                                                (
                                                                  value,
                                                                  key3
                                                                ) => {
                                                                  return (
                                                                    <option
                                                                      value={
                                                                        arraySelect2[
                                                                          key2
                                                                        ][key3]
                                                                      }
                                                                    >
                                                                      {
                                                                        arraySelect2[
                                                                          key2
                                                                        ][key3]
                                                                      }{" "}
                                                                      Equipos
                                                                    </option>
                                                                  );
                                                                }
                                                              )}
                                                            </select>
                                                          )}{" "}
                                                          {key2 !==
                                                            rows.length - 2 && (
                                                            <select
                                                              onChange={(e) =>
                                                                handleChange(
                                                                  key2 + 1,
                                                                  e.target.value
                                                                )
                                                              }
                                                              name=""
                                                              id=""
                                                              disabled={true}
                                                            >
                                                              <option value="seleccione">
                                                                Seleccione
                                                              </option>
                                                              {arraySelect2[
                                                                key2
                                                              ].map(
                                                                (
                                                                  value,
                                                                  key3
                                                                ) => {
                                                                  return (
                                                                    <option
                                                                      value={
                                                                        arraySelect2[
                                                                          key2
                                                                        ][key3]
                                                                      }
                                                                    >
                                                                      {
                                                                        arraySelect2[
                                                                          key2
                                                                        ][key3]
                                                                      }{" "}
                                                                      Equipos
                                                                    </option>
                                                                  );
                                                                }
                                                              )}
                                                            </select>
                                                          )}{" "}
                                                          Ubicados en la
                                                          {key2 ===
                                                            rows.length - 2 && (
                                                            <div
                                                              className="col-sm-2"
                                                              style={{
                                                                top: "-27px",
                                                                right: "-135%"
                                                              }}
                                                            >
                                                              <button
                                                                type="submit"
                                                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                                                onClick={() => {
                                                                  setSelect_select2(
                                                                    selectedNumbers[
                                                                      key2 + 1
                                                                    ]
                                                                  );
                                                                }}
                                                              >
                                                                crear
                                                              </button>
                                                            </div>
                                                          )}
                                                        </font>{" "}
                                                      </label>
                                                    </>
                                                  )}
                                                </div>
                                              );
                                            })}
                                        </div>

                                        <div
                                          className="col-sm-2"
                                          style={{ top: "-40px" }}
                                        >
                                          {rows.map((e, index) => (
                                            <Row
                                              nombre={e.nombre}
                                              index={index}
                                              onChange={(index, value) =>
                                                handleOnChange(index, value)
                                              }
                                              key={index}
                                            />
                                          ))}
                                        </div>
                                      </div>{" "}
                                    </font>{" "}
                                  </label>
                                </font>{" "}
                              </label>
                            </>
                          )}
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                </div>
              ) : (
                <></>
              )}

              {numberIni2 && (
                <input
                  onClick={() => resetFormtodo()}
                  type="button"
                  value="Reiniciar"
                />
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default test;
```

[image: Edit new]

Pruébalo para ver si era lo que estabas buscando.

Comment: solo hay un detalle cuando los select se desactivan se esta borrando el numero que se selecciono.

Comment: Ok. Ya agregué la solución a ese problema a mi respuesta. Pero guíate por el código del SandBox, porque el que puse acá quedó desactualizado. Eso es porque Stack Overflow limita la cantidad de caracteres que puede tener una respuesta, y si agrego el código completo no entra todo.

Comment: listo me sirvió muchas gracias, tengo otra pregunta, tengo un boton que se llama reiniciar lo que hace es borrarme todo el formulario y me deja en la parte donde dice "1 clasificados por grupo" , pero el problema es que al seleccionar algún valor del select me esta creando de forma automática los otros selects dinamicos y lo que necesito es que me quede como se hace en la secuencia, cree otra pregunta pero si me puedes ayudar te lo agradecería, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499485/al-darle-reiniciar-a-mi-formulario-no-me-esta-limpiando-todos-los-campos-react